# php script unable to write in folder

Tags: php, apache, fopen, fwrite

I am facing a strange issue. I have simple php script as shown below

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("/var/www/html/***/templates_c/testnewfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "John Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Jane Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

I have found out that the http server is running as apache user. I have given ownership of the folder to this user.

If I ssh to the server and run the script as `php write.php` it is able to write a new file into the template_c folder, however if I hit the script via browser like `example.com/write.php` I get the error - `Unable to open file!`

I am not able to understand why this might be happening, the folder has correct ownership and I have even given it recursive 777 just to try things out, but I still get the same result

**EDIT**

Here is a snippet from the console, showing the ownership of html folder

```
0 drwxr-xr-x. 2 root   root      6 Jun  9  2019 cgi-bin
4 drwxrwxr-x. 4 apache apache 4096 Dec  9 17:51 html
```

Also here is the snippet showing the user webserver user is apache

```
$ ps -ef | egrep '(httpd|apache2|apache)' | grep -v `whoami` | grep -v root | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}'
apache
```

Comment: owner should be apache, or apache should have rights to write

Comment: @AhmedSunny The owner is apache what do you mean rights to write, for now it has 777 permission.

Comment: i tried your code on my server from browser, it works fine

Comment: the folder templates_c should also have same rights or group,

Comment: @AhmedSunny it seems to be some other issue related with either the OS or particular env. I am not able to replicate this in any of my other boxes. This just won't run. Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: you can try delete this folder, and recreate it with the script from php, dont create manually, because this script works fine for me on linux server with apache as user,